Next door neighbor's smoke alarm keeps chirping every 30 seconds
My neighbor in the next house has a detached garage and there is a smoke alarm in that garage that is chirping every 30 seconds for a few days.
The garage has an open window facing my house with a distance of about 5 feet, so the noise is pretty loud and disturbing at night.
I talked to them about it but they said they couldn't hear anything and told me it's crazy I'm disturbed by that. I offered to change the battery for them but they declined.
Any advice on how to deal with this?

This question might be a better fit for Law.SE or Interpersonal Skills SE. You're basically having a noise problem with something on your neighbor's property, and the neighbor is being a jerk. Maybe the city or the cops can help.

The battery will die by itself in a few days or weeks.  Engaging in any kind of sabotage or law suit will create far more stress in your life than just enduring this til it stops.  Obviously the neighbor won't replace the battery so it will never happen again.

@jay613  Doing an experiment with a CO detector.  Going on six months now and it is still chirping away.

@jay613 I wouldn't count on that. I had one at the lodge that was chirping like that, and did it for more than 5 years.  I had earnestly believed it had been negligently left behind when a screwed-on interlocked ceiling was added, and I had never had the bandwidth to tear open the ceiling and find it.  When I finally did, I was able to locate it to not above the ceiling at all, but on a shelf. Assumptions!

It may not have a battery that can be changed, which complicates things.

@Harper-ReinstateMonica temperature can do funny things.  I've had them only beep at night, when it's cooler, for example.  So it may or may not have been intermittent.  A dodgy cell in the 9V battery could also mean that the voltage stays low for a long time

The smoke alarm could chirp for years.   If you can see the alarm it will flash when it beeps (most types).   At night if you are videoing you should be able to get a faint light and beep every 30 seconds.   I would knock on the neighbors door at about 10 PM with the video on your phone.
I would then just tell them that you will call the cops unless they take it down and show that it is working right.   Just be honest and tell them you will call the cops at midnight.   That way they know they will be woken up too.
Note that even with a dead battery, if it is hard wired it can be reset to 12 hours and will start beeping after that.

I like this answer but it feels like this isn't a diy question when I read it

If other neighbors can hear it bring them in as supporting evidence. If they can't...
You can ask the police to check on it, but if it isn't loud enough to be violating a noise ordinance there isn't much they can do.
Make darned sure you know whose house it is coming from. I've had beeps that seemed to be from outside but were my own fault. The neighbor you have complained to may turn out to be innocent.

I can reinforce that thing about making sure you know where it's coming from. I once spent many minutes at 3am working out which of the alarms in my own house was misbehaving. The sound was echoing so that when I was upstairs it sounded like downstairs, and vice versa.

Tell them that if they don't replace the battery or let you do it for them, you'll have no choice but to call the police (or other relevant authority) next time it is keeping you awake at 3am. Repeat. Make it clear that you're willing to do the work for them but it has to be fixed because you can't sleep! Then do call the police (and if necessary, suggest to them that they should wake up the neighbour to open up the garage for them ....)
If that doesn't work (unlikely, I hope), the next stage would be a solicitor's letter indicating that it's a statutory nuisance and that when you have to pay for a hotel to get a decent night's sleep, they will be sued for the cost. The danger, though, is that when you come to sell your house, you will have to declare this dispute with your neighbour, which could reduce the value of your house!
The worst thing about these alarms is that they chirp when the battery voltage drops below a threshold. Trouble is that for any battery, the colder it gets, the lower the voltage gets. So this warning always starts in the early hours, often on the first really cold night of the Autumn. And it has stopped by the time you complain to the neighbour so he may think you are complaining about nothing. Next night it starts again.

Call the firefighters telling that you hear a smoke alarm beeping and that there may be a fire hazard in the garage next-door, but you don't see (yet) any smoke.
They'll decide if its an emergency or not.

You’re really suggesting that the OP handle this by calling the fire department and falsely (through omission) claiming their house might be on fire?

it is not false: OP does not know what's goimg on inside, and is right getting anxious having a fire hazard next to his property, it may be just the dryer, used at night, that malfunction or is full of lint, making smoke setting the alarm off, the electric car charger poorly installed that overheat the wires when charging.
There's an actual possibility of a fire and should be taken seriously, OP should report it to ensure he is not in a dangerous situation.

And when the OP calls, would you advise that they volunteer the information that it's been chirping continuously for several days now, which would definitely indicate that it has not been "set off" and is instead just reporting a low battery?

And even more to the point, would you advise that the OP explain to the fire department that, as they stated in their question, their reason for calling has nothing to do with worrying about a fire risk and is instead just because they're annoyed about the noise?

The reason is a bad smoke detector or a smoke hazard itself.
As said OP should be concerned about his safety (fire propagate quite easily), the sensor annoys on purpose: to keep people safe safe alerting in case of issues.
